# Loop through each item against a cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I have a list of port number and I want to see which program is using that port. I want to filter the [`Get-Networkstatistics`](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-NetworkStatistics-66057d71) cmdlet to show me only certain ports that are in the `port.txt` file. I modified the

```
Get-NetworkStatistics  | Select-Object ComputerName, LocalPort, ProcessName
```

to loop through only the port numbers I provide. However, the `$result` variable is not storing anything and the output is null. What am I doing wrong?

```
$file = .\ports.txt

foreach ( $port in $file )
{ 
    $result += Get-NetworkStatistics  |
               Select-Object ComputerName, LocalPort, ProcessName |
               Where-Object {$_.LocalPort -eq $port}
}
$result | Export-Csv .\networkports.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you want to filter before doing Select, that way you have to select lower objects.

```
$result = @() #array
foreach ( $port in $file )
{ 
$result += Get-NetworkStatistics  | Where-Object {$_.LocalPort -eq $port} | Select-Object ComputerName, LocalPort, ProcessName 
}
$result | Export-Csv .\networkports.csv
```

As for the actual problem itself, I believe it is due to [scoping](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx). You need to declare variable before the loop, so it is available in the loop, and after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the Get-Content cmdlet:
`$file = Get-Content "path_to_ports.txt'`

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
$file = .\ports.txt
```

Doesn't read the file into the variable. Use `Get-Content` for that.

Also, you don't need a loop. `Get-Content` reads the input file into an array of strings, so you can use the `-contains` operator for checking if the list contains a given local port:

```
$ports = Get-Content '.\ports.txt'
Get-NetworkStatistics |
    Where-Object { $ports -contains $_.LocalPort } |
    Select-Object ComputerName, LocalPort, ProcessName |
    Export-Csv '.\networkports.csv' -NoType
```

On PowerShell v3 or newer you can also use the `-in` operator, which feels a bit more "natural" to most users:

```
$ports = Get-Content '.\ports.txt'
Get-NetworkStatistics |
    Where-Object { $_.LocalPort -in $ports } |
    Select-Object ComputerName, LocalPort, ProcessName |
    Export-Csv '.\networkports.csv' -NoType
```